# Polymer get parameter value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I defined a custom element "wineItem"

http://pastebin.com/VWh2Dk4J (I couldn't paste here the code)

When I want to call this element in a page I do something like this:

```
            <wine-item id_wine={{params.id_wine}}></wine-item>
```

The problem is that the value of "id_wine" inside the "wine-item" in the ready function is undefined, but in the html value appears properly.

What can I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

The problem is that sometimes the ready function doesnt load when its ready.

Just put a timer and it works!

```
    ready: function()
    {
        this.async(function ()
          { 
             ....
          },50);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `id-wine` inside `wine-item` is undefined in the ready function because you did not explicitly create it as a property for the `wine-item` element. Your element should look like this :

```js
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
 
<dom-module name="wine-item">
  <template>
    <span>{{id_wine}}</span>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
 
      is:'wine-item',
      // Adding properties 
      properties:{
        
        id_wine:String // type can be Object Array or Number , refers to polymer doc
      
      },
 
      ready: function()
      {
        // Now you can access id_wine in your ready function with `this`
        this.id_wine='idtest';
        
        //  $  allow to access element in the local DOM like <span id='id_wine'></span>
       // this.$.id_wine = this.id_wine;
       
       /* console.log(this.id_wine);
        console.log(this.$.id_wine)*/
 
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

```html
<wine-item id-wine="newIdTest"></wine-item>
```

Now if your intention is to create an element with id (`Javascript id`) it is not possible, you can do it in the `html` when using the element like native html components

```
<wine-item id="id-of-my-element"></wine-item>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but It doesnt work. "id_wine" is a parameter of the element, so I dont want to give it a value in ready function. I just need to take the value of this parameter.

Comment: be clear on what your are trying to achieve, if you want some help

Answer (score 0):

```
<dom-module name="wine-item">
```

is wrong, this should be:

```
<dom-module id="wine-item">
```

Maybe that is the reason why your variable is undefined

#### Edit

To access to variable using javascript you will have to use as follows:

```
this.yourVariable
```

### Edit

My bad, I did not know that is possible to use "name" instead of "id".

```
 <dom-module name="hello-test">
  <template>
    hello <span>{{name}}</span>
    <button on-tap="showData">show data</button>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is:"hello-test",
      name:{
        type:String
      },
      showData: function(){
        console.log(this.name);
      },
    });

  </script>
</dom-module>
  <hello-test name="Alex"></hello-test>
```